# How to change ace editor theme

Tags: javascript

I have following code. How can I set theme using below code?

```
(function initAce() {
    var aceTheme;
    if (localStorage.getItem("theme")) {
      aceTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    } else {
      aceTheme = "ace/theme/chrome";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `setTheme`

```
var ace = ace.edit("editor");
ace.setTheme(aceTheme);
```